# Does using Environment Hub negate need for SSO in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, single-sign-on, environment-hub

I'm testing SSO w openId connect (Azure AD as auth provider)

I'm trying to better understand how I should set it up so that I can use SSO to authenticate to sandboxes that are spun up from prod.

I'm considering these approaches:

- design my registrationHandler to determine environment and parse the sandbox username appropriately, so that it returns the correct user
- dont bother w sandbox SSO, just use environment hub in prod (i have never used hub..But I think that it can do this)
- something else?

My sense is that I could just use environment hub to connect myself (admin) to all sandboxes and users to the UAT sandbox only, and that would eliminate the need for me to use Azure SSO in sandboxes.  However I have no idea how SSO behaves with sandbox refreshes, nor do I have access to environment hub, so am looking for guidance.